# Do Stack Exchange websites know my location?

Tags: support, privacy, cookies

Do Stack Exchange websites know my location?

Stack Exchange uses cookies, right?
Do my coordinates go to some database?

Comment: TL;DR, taken from the dupe, the official reply to "Is my location captured and stored against my name?" is: *Only if you type it into your profile. But keep in mind that IP addresses can be geolocated to general areas, so that's basically like storing a location in disguise*.